# MPMoviePlayerController setFullScreen animated bug on iOS 8.0 but not on iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have and MPMoviePlayerController in my project. I tried to run it on iOS 8.0. When I play the video for the first time, It works fine and I have the progress bar of the video. Then I quit and try to play the video for the second time. It still works except than I don't have the progress bar of the video. I said in the title "setFullScreen:animated" because I also had the error "CGImageCreate : invalid image size 0x0" so I guess It can come frome here.
Also, it appears to work without any problem on iOS 8.1, so I think it's bug corrected by Apple. Maybe someone have heard something about it.

Here is some code when the Controller is created and setted :

```
_moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.model.filePath]];
_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
_moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_moviePlayer.view.frame = self.imageButton.frame;
[self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];

[_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[_moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Any guess ?

Comment: I think there are some bugs with MPMoviePlayerController in iOS 8